# Unable to $unset field in MongoDB nested document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a document that looks like the following

```
{
  "list" :{
    "friends": [
        {
        "Name": "John",
        "Contact": "xyz",
        "Code": "B"
        },
        {
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Contact": "abc",
        "Code": "A"
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to delete a field using the `$unset` operator based on a filter. My code looks like:

```
result = db.collection.update_many({"list.friends.code": "A"}, 
         {"$unset": {"list.friends.$.Name": "", "list.frieds.$.Contact": ""}})
```

However, I get `pymongo.errors.WriteError: Invalid BSON field name 'list.friends.$.Name'`

Comment: Kindly note that you've "code" using lowercase characters only in your query which does not match the "Code" in your example data... Also, "frieds" should probably be "friends"...

Comment: Also, which MongoDB version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
result = db.collection.update_many({"list.friends": { $elemMatch: { "Code":"A"}}}, 
     {"$unset": {"list.friends.$.Name": "", "list.friends.$.Contact": ""}})
```

Comment: Still getting "WriteError: Invalid BSON field name 'list.friends.$.Name'"

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the driver?

Comment: Yep. It's 3.6.0

Comment: That's the MongoDB version but what about the pymongo version?